# Does a single cycle satisfy the definition of a necklace?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

A necklace is defined to be a list of cycles $C_1,...,C_k$ s.t $u \in C_1$ and $v \in C_k$ where consecutive cycles share exactly one vertex and non-consecutive cycles are disjoint.

I believe that a single cycle does satisfy this definition vacuously, since it has neither consecutive cycles nor non-consecutive cycles. Am I correct?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "such that $u\in C_1$ and $v\in C_k$". Can we just forget about this phrase?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter $u,v \in V(G)$, where $G$ is the necklace itself, if that helps. So $u$ is "in the first cycle" and $v$ is "in the $k^{th}$ cycle"

Comment: @ChristianBlatter with much more experience, I now realize that indeed, yes, we can forget that phrase.